# Is there a way to UPDATE data and SELECT updated ids on output in the same query using entity framework core?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'd like to update a set of rows based on a simple linq criteria and return updated ids. I know how to do it with raw sql using OUTPUT statement, but I don't want to mix raw sql code with linq statements.Is there a way to do this by linq?

Example:

UPDATE Foo
SET Bar = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
WHERE createDate not null

Comment: Can you share with us what you want to do actually? Like your sql query, requirement etc.

Comment: Sure, I edited post and add some simple example. All I want to do it's update rows with where condition and returns updated rows IDs with single query.

Comment: Do you use mssql?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is using INSERTED.Id it should be deleted.Id.

You can use the below update statement:

```
UPDATE Foo SET Bar = 1 OUTPUT deleted.Id WHERE createDate is not null
```

Well I don't think that you can do it with plain linq.

I could not test it but the code should be something like :

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE Foo SET Bar = 1 OUTPUT deleted.Id WHERE createDate is not null";
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // do something with result
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but it's misunderstanding. I need a linq query that's using entity framework core 2.1.

Comment: I updated my answer, I don't think that you can do it with plain linq.

Answer (score 0):

With a caveat...

```
var ids = new List<int>();

await _db.Foos
   .Where(x => x.CreateDate != null)
   .ForEachAsync(f => { 
         f.Bar = 1;
         ids.Add(f.Id);
    });
```

I'm pretty sure this wont create the SQL you desire though. More than likely it will do an update per entity in an iteration. However, I dont have EF in front of me to test.

Comment: As you suspected :-) I also need to get ids on output as result

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about the differences between `ef-core` with full `entity framework`.

In entity framework none of your changes is actually saved in the database until you call `SaveChanges`. If you assert that you are the only user of your `dbContext` object, you can ask this `dbContext` object for collections of the objects that will be inserted and updated when you call `SaveChanges`.

As no one else is using your `dbContext` object, you can be sure that between asking for these collections and the actual SaveChanges nothing changes:

```
using (var dbContext =  new MyDbContext(...))
{
    // Insert and Change some items
    ...

    // ask the DbContext which items are Inserted / Changed
    var changeTracker = dbContext.ChangeTracker;

    // get all inserted items:
    var allInsertedItems = changeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Added);

    // or get the original and changed value of changed Contracts:
    var allChangedContracts = changeTracker.Entries<Contract>()
        .Where(contact => contract.State == Enitystate.Modified)
        .Select(contract => new
        {
            OriginalValue = contract.OriginalValue,
            ChangedValue = contract.Value,
        });

    // when ready to save the changes:
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Your example works on entries that was modified or added  - they are stored in ChangeTracker and I need work on db entries, however thanks :)